# Sonar Qube sample plugin not working

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm trying to write a SonarQube plugin for Java so I cloned a copy of java-custom-rules and with out any modification  I build that and put the jar into extensions/plugins of SonarQube! and I run sonar-runner.bat on built-in Hello World(sonar-runner) sample project!

Now my problem is that the issues created by this plugin are not shown in SonarQube web interface! I also checked that it runs my plugins and the answer was YES(using debug info)!

Can anyone  help?

Comment: Did you enable the plugin's rule(s) on your quality profile(s)?

Comment: No. how should I do that?

Comment: It depends on your version of SonarQube; in versions before 4.4 you will need to open the "Quality Profiles" page and manage rules from there, but since 4.4 activation of rules on profiles is managed from the "Rules" page.

Comment: my rule is listed in rules page but there is no way to disable or enable it. also there is nothing related to my rules in **Quality Profiles** page

Comment: Ok i wasn't logged in! :) every thins work now! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an example here http://qualilogy.com/en/plsql-analysis-sonarqube-plsql-quality-profile/

Hope it helps.